# Does this objective-c code create a strong reference cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting, strong-references

I am working in someone else's iOS project. ARC is (and to the best of my knowledge always has been) enabled. The code is littered with button-press handlers that create an instance of some view controller, set its delegate to self, and then show it, e.g.,

```
- (IBAction)keyButton:(id)sender {
    MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

MyViewController shows a spin widget for choosing a musical key. Once chosen, the user presses back to use the selected key to make music. Those are the only user interactions, and there are no background processes etc.

In the MyViewController.h file, the delegate is declared as follows:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    id <ModuleUpdateDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) id delegate;
```

I have two questions:

1. Why might the original author have chosen to create a new instance
   of MyViewController with every button press?
2. Who owns each such instance? [When] does it get destroyed? Since it
   holds a strong reference to its delegate, *is the current
   implementation creating a strong reference cycle [with each button
   press]*?

My own instinct is to create a private, MyViewController * property in the delegate, which gets loaded on the first button press only. Then I would make the delegate property in MyViewController weak instead of strong, per the general recommendation. But like I said, the current implementation is quite ubiquitous, so I am leery of changing anything without first understanding how it works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it doesn't matter who `MyViewController` retains, it matters who retains the instance of `MyViewController`.

In the code you posted, the strong reference to `MyViewController` is held by `self.navigationController`. As soon as `MyViewController` is popped, then its retain count will hit 0 and it will be released. As long as `controller.delegate` doesn't retain `controller`, there is no cycle.

That said, you must be very careful with strong back references (eg. things like delegates). When in doubt use Instruments to check for retain cycles or memory leaks.

---

My advice: be cautions. Turn the strong delegate into a weak delegate if possible. Even if there is no retain cycle right now, you could easily create one without realizing it.

Comment: "the strong reference to MyViewController is held by self.navigationController." Yes, I see now from the Apple documentation on encapsulating data that, "Local variables (and non-property instance variables) also maintain strong references to objects by default."

Answer (score 2):

Delegate references are weak by convention.

Normally, you create an object, hold a strong reference to it, and set yourself as it's delegate. (and the pointer to the delegate is weak.) That way there is only a strong reference one way.

In your case your code is doing the opposite. The object (a MyViewController) is being created in a local variable, then forgotten. The MyViewController class' delegate property is strong. So there is no strong reference to the MyViewController object, but there IS a strong reference to the delegate.

As Jeffery says, you don't appear to have a retain cycle now, but if later you decide that you need to keep a pointer to your MyViewController object then you will likely create a retain cycle.